# Read Linux Path and append all data

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to read all csv files present in a Linux path and store it in a single data frame using Python.

I am able to read the files but while storing, each file is getting created as dictionary object ex: df['file1'],df['file2'] and so on.

Please let me know how can I store each csv file into separate data frame dynamically and then combine them to store in a single data frame.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pls show us the code you uisng to read the files..

Comment: I'm not sure if you need python for that. One can easily use the `cat` (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html) command to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

dataframes = []
for p in Path("path/to/data").iterdir():
    if p.suffix == ".csv":
        dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(p))
        
df = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

Or if you want to include subdirectories

from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

```
path = Path("path/to/data")
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in path.glob("**/*.csv")], ignore_index=True)
```